# Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) on a Dell Developer Edition XPS 13 Laptop?

Tags: 18.04, kernel, dell, laptop, hardware

I ordered a Dell Developer Edition XPS 13 7390 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled. I am tempted to upgrade to the latest 18.04 point release including the updated HWE kernel.

Is there a disadvantage to doing this? Are there any kernel tweaks placed by Dell in their standard install that I will lose by going to the HWE kernel? What about the rest of the software preinstalled on the laptop?

Comment: When you fully-upgrade your system, you'll always go to the latest point release.  HWE kernel is enabled if you install with 18.04.2 or later, but isn't for earlier ISOs. If you fully-upgrade an earlier non-HWE system, it remains non-HWE unless specifically changed to HWE.

Comment: Check what kernel it's using. If 4.15 then your not on the HWE, 4.18 or 5.x then you are. I'd be surprised if it's not using HWE.  Also sounds like a question for Dell support..

Answer (score 1):

My advice is: if you are unsure, and going to stick with Ubuntu 18.04, then stick with the OES installation of Ubuntu by Dell. This is an installation tested by the Dell developers, and which is under warranty. The kernel is "under the hood" anyway. In the best case, you won't notice anything after upgrading the kernel, in the (not unlikely) less best case, you may bump into some issues.